# SMS body text for html with % for percent sign crashes android app

Tags: android, html, sms

Whenever I put a % in the body of my sms html link like:
sms (? or & separating depending on ios android) :

```
a href="sms:555555555?body=Hello123 % testing!"target="_parent">            
Click /a
```

It crashes my messaging app on android, but on iOS it's fine. I tried to encode it as well, but that didn't seem to work. Any clue on how to escape this?

EDIT: This only happens with Google Messages, Samsung Messages is ok

Comment: Can you check what happens when you put in a double percent, like %% Also, I don't think it is legal html to have the spaces in the body. Is the + instead.

Comment: Still crashes on a %% I've tried with + also instead of spaces, same thing

Comment: So, Google Messages Fails, but Samsung Messages works. (Note Samsung Messages also sends the +'s so I'll not use the +)

Comment: Did you try  &#37;   ?

Comment: If I do &#37; it will break the message up and only show the part before that. I have emailed google support as well, I think the % is some recent bug. Every app that opens messages are different, so just always have to keep checking, I think this is a new bug

Answer (score 0):

try to write with symbol like ©`<p>Copyright &copy;</p>`

Comment: That didn't seem to work it needs to show up on SMS, tried &percnt;

Answer (score 0):

Try to encode percent like

```
a href="sms:555555555?body=Hello123 %25 testing!"target="_parent">
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and spent a lot of time but solution was pretty simple.
Need to replace '%' with one of these:
[percent sign variations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1fgO.png)

SMS body encoding function:

```js
function encodeSMSText(text) {
  const updatedText = text.replace(/%/g, String.fromCharCode(0xFF05));
   return encodeURIComponent(updatedText)
    .replace(/[!'()*]/g, function(c) {
      return '%' + c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16);
    });
}
```